# Can't install MS Project 2013 after installing Office 2013

Tags: windows, ms-project, failed-installation, office-2013

I'm trying to install Microsoft Project Professional 2013. The fact is I already installed MS Office 2013, and I had no issues with that. now, i'm getting an error message and the installation fails. any idea about how i can fix that ?

I'm running Windows 7 32 Bits with all the updates installed.

Comment: i got it in french, but I'll try to translate : Microsoft Office 2013 does not support upgrading from a preview version of Microsoft Office 2013.you must uninstall those preview versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove all the beta versions of Office 2013. After this I could install Office 2013 and Visio 2013 without any problems and the cause is probably the Prooffing Tools. I had the same issue. Here is small guide to remove Prooffing tools (That are not appearing to appwiz.cpl = system application).

> 1. Go to %windir%\installer
> 2. Right click titlebar and select subject
> 3. Go each msi through (Subject value) and you'll find some prooffing tools preview installed. (or something else from preview)
> 4. Right click it and choose "Uninstall"
> 5. After that you should be able to install Office 2013 RTM

You can also see if [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501) can help you.

Comment: the fact is that i don't have any beta version. anyway, i'm gonna try this and i'll let you know. thank you for your time